# Pass a javascript variable through a hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, I have javascript to calculate a dynamic price for an HTML form. The code is as follows:

```
jQuery("input[name='Amount']").change(function() {
if (isNaN(parseFloat(this.value)) || !isFinite(this.value)) {
jQuery(this).val('');
return false;
}
var calc = parseFloat(this.value) * 0.95;
jQuery(this).parents("form").find("input[name='price']").val(calc);
});
```

This, with this input:

```
<input class="irrelevant typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="Amount"/>
```

The javascript takes that value, calculates the price, and I want it to fill this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="price" value=""/>
```

I believe my javascript is correct. What do I need to do to the price  to make it work?

Comment: Why did you change the "original code".

Comment: `"input[name='Amount']".value` is wrong, it should be `this.value` as it is in the original

Comment: Because I didn't really know what I was doing.

Comment: @dmullings I edited the question, can you take a look at that?

Comment: Unrelated to your question... but I hope you are using the hidden input field solely for front-end purposes and don't actually pass it to the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have these items wrapped in a `<form>` tag.

```
<form>
    <input class="irrelevant typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="Amount"/>
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value=""/>
</form>


jQuery("input[name='Amount']").change(function() {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(this.value)) || !isFinite(this.value)) {
        jQuery(this).val('');
        return false;
    }
    var calc = parseFloat(this.value) * 0.95;
    jQuery(this).parents("form").find("input[name='price']").val(calc);
});
```

I have a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/P55ge/

In the demo I have made the price input a text field instead of a hidden field for ease of seeing the value being set.

Also note, that the field is only updated when you enter a valid number and then click off the field input. The following quote is from the jquery documentation for `.change()` http://api.jquery.com/change/

> Now when the second option is selected from the dropdown, the alert is
>   displayed. It is also displayed if you change the text in the field
>   and then click away. If the field loses focus without the contents
>   having changed, though, the event is not triggered.